# javascript delay adding display none on fadeOut

Tags: jquery

I am trying to make this a smooth fadeIn fadeOut splash, but it's adding "display none" immediately.

```
$('.home #splash').removeClass('car-accident')
                  .addClass('personal-injury')
                  .delay(4000)
                  .fadeOut(400);
```

Comment: Can you add a demo please (snippet code or jsfidle). it will be easier to help you

Comment: Its not so easy to know excactly what you want without a fiddle. But can you try this: .fadeOut( "slow" );

You also have the option to delay: .fadeOut().delay(4000)

Comment: https://jsbin.com/munaxifuse/edit?js,output

Answer (score 1):

You need the jQuery UI library aswell. You can use the `.toggleClass()` function that will be loaded from `jquery.ui.js`

I made you an example:
https://jsfiddle.net/C0dekid/pzdrm6uf/1/

Let me know :)

Comment: Didn't realize I needed the jQuery UI library, thanks. The only thing is I need to put a few classes in there, so toggle won't work. I added the UI library on my local, and it's still causing the bg image to disappear completely.

Comment: What do you mean by putting a few classes? You can take a look at the `.switchClass()` function: http://api.jqueryui.com/switchclass maybe is that what you are looking for? Let me know! :)

Comment: I am basically trying to build a carousel, with several different background images. I generally use Bootstrap, but want to do something more custom. So there will probably be 5 or 6 different "slides" with different background images.

Comment: Alright! Than you need to think a different way. You can do something with ul/li's for example: http://blog.moore-interactive.net/2011/05/very-simple-jquery-slideshow-based-on-ul-li

Comment: You're welcome! If you need help with anything, just ask!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  $("#splash").removeClass("car-accident").addClass("personal-injury");
   $(".personal-injury").delay(400).fadeOut(400);
});
```

Comment: A little explanation would be helpful. What was the problem and how does your answer solve it?

Comment: Please add some comments about your solution on why and how it solves the problem